# How can we run automated tests using webdriver in chrome to test an app which should also work in offline mode?

Tags: google-chrome, webdriver, watir-webdriver, offlineapps

I have tried adding ' profile['network.manage-offline-status'] = true' but this doesn't seem to be turning the chrome browser to offline mode

```
        profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
        profile['default_search_provider.enabled'] = false
        profile['network.manage-offline-status'] = true
        profile['homepage'] = 'about:blank'
```

Answer (score 0):

Googling that profile setting, it looks like it's only a Firefox setting, so will have no effect on an instance of Chrome.

Reading a little about Chrome, it appears there is no simple option for going into an "offline mode".

You could test the functionality through watir-webdriver by manually disconnecting your computer from the Internet, but that's not a good solution for automated tests.

Comment: Yes, I found this for Firefox, but thought it would work for Chrome but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Chrome browser and java selenium then below is the code which I have used:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("app.isConnected = true;");
```

"app.isConnected = true;" : is the console command which I am using to goto Offline and then back to Online